# C2DM Php implementation

Tags: php, android, android-c2dm

I have tried using the php code found in the following link 
https://github.com/lytsing/c2dm-php

I am getting the response http code as "0".

Comment: c2dm has been deprecated. Why not look into `GCM` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a different php c2dm implementation in the below link
http://code.google.com/p/plic-opensource-mti2012/source/browse/trunk/server/library/c2dm.php?r=72

It's working fin now.